# Abstract inline Angularjs filter

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

New to angular!

I've set up a very basic filter of which I'm quite happy with. Yet I want to transpose the inline filter to a `.filter()` function - I hope to use it like `filter: dataFilter`, or something similar.

So, currently I have some select fields:

```
<select ng-model="search.foo"><!-- options --></select>
<select ng-model="search.bar"><!-- options --></select>
```

And an `ng-repeat` of the sorted data:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in response.data | filter:{foo: search.foo, bar: search.bar}">
    <!-- display sorted data -->
</div>
```

Above in the `ng-repeat` is what I would call the inline filter of which I want to abstract.

How do I go about doing this?

All guidance appreciated.

---

My end game aim is to show a message when there an no results in the filter. I believe the filter needs to be "abstracted" in order for this to work? Something along the lines of:

```
<p ng-show="(response.data | filter:blahFilter).length == 0">No results found.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would really advice you to move this to the controller. Then inside there just use your filter as a function call

```
$scope.myData = $filter('blaFilter')(response.data)
```

then

```
<p ng-show="myData.length == 0">No results found.</p>
```

Comment: Remember to inject the $filter in the controller

Comment: Yes I agree with all that - I'm more wondering how do I create that filter?

Comment: You don't need to do that, if you have already created the filter in your angular app, that filter will be accessible as "inline" and directly from the JS. If not you must just create a filter and both approaches will work. Maybe I did not understand the question, do you need help with creating a filter?

Comment: I do not have a blaFilter. I also do not know how to create one that simulates - filter:{foo: search.foo, bar: search.bar}